# jQuery - selected attribute on options doesn't show in FireBug

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, firebug

Why?

when I select a option in a select field, the `selected="selected"` attribute still stays on the previous option. But visually you can see that the new option is active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting an option from the dropdown doesn't modify the `selected` attribute in the DOM. But if you query the current value using `$('#selectId').val()` it would return the value of the currently selected option.

Comment: but how can I change the selected option with jQuery then?

Comment: @Alexandra, like this `$('#selectId').val('123')`, where `123` represents the value of the option you want to get selected.

Comment: this is weird. why does the option have a selected attribute then?

Comment: @Alexandra, so that you could decide which option would be initially selected when the page first loads.

Comment: but if jquery uses val(), this should be done trugh the value attribute. but in w3c select doesn't have a value attribute. this is really confusing...